# Как использовать объект одного класса в другом классе? Python, PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть два класса.

Мне нужно использовать объект класса `MyWidget`, допустим `self.A`, и использовать его в классе `SecondWindow`, как это реализовать?

```
class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('FirstWindow')

        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()
        self.C = set()
        self.V = ""
        self.T = ""

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.Set_Variant)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Set_A)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Set_B)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.Set_C)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.Universe_Set)

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.show_window_3)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.show_window_4)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.show_window_5)


    def show_window_2(self):
        self.w2 = SecondWindow()
        self.w2.show()

    def show_window_3(self):
        self.w3 = ThirdWindow()
        self.w3.show()

    def show_window_4(self):
        self.w4 = FourthWindow()
        self.w4.show()

    def show_window_5(self):
        self.w5 = FifthWindow()
        self.w5.show()

    def Set_Variant(self):
        Name = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        G = int(self.textEdit_2.toPlainText())
        N = int(self.textEdit_3.toPlainText())
        M = self.textEdit_4.toPlainText()
        if M == "ІВ": N+=2
        R = str((N+G%60)%30+1)
        S = str(Name) + "\nМій варіант: " + str(R)
        self.label_10.setText(S)
        print(S)

    def Universe_Set(self):
        self.V = self.textEdit_11.toPlainText()
        self.T = self.textEdit_12.toPlainText()

    def Set_A(self):
        F_1 = self.textEdit_5.toPlainText()
        if F_1 == "":
            a = self.textEdit_8.toPlainText()
            self.A = set(int(x) for x in a.split()) 
        else:
            print(self.V)
            print(self.T)
            while len(self.A) < int(F_1):
                self.A.add(random.randint(int(self.V),int(self.T)))
        print(self.A)

    def Set_B(self):
        F_2 = self.textEdit_6.toPlainText()
        if F_2 == "":
            b = self.textEdit_9.toPlainText()
            self.B = set(int(x) for x in b.split())
        else:
            while len(self.B) <= int(F_2):
                self.B.add(random.randint(int(self.V),int(self.T)))
        print(self.B)

    def Set_C(self):
        F_3 = self.textEdit_7.toPlainText()
        if F_3 == "":
            c = self.textEdit_10.toPlainText()
            self.C = set(int(x) for x in c.split())
        else:
            while len(self.C) <= int(F_3):
                self.C.add(random.randint(int(self.V),int(self.T)))
        print(self.C)    

############################################################################################################################

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Window_2):               
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('SecondWindow')

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Print_Set)

    def Print_Set(self):
        self.label_6.setText(A)
        self.label_7.setText(B)
        self.label_8.setText(C)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании экземпляра `self.w2 = SecondWindow(self)` передайте в качестве родителя `self`

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Window_2):               
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('SecondWindow')

        self.parent = parent                               # +++
        print(self.parent.A)                               # <---

        ...


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        self.A = set()

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)

    def show_window_2(self):
        self.w2 = SecondWindow(self)                        # +++ self
        self.w2.show()
    ...
```